# Disable WordPress Email/Username at The Registration Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a website using WordPress. My website provides a registration page where users can enter several information in a form.

Is it possible to disable/delete the email and username at the registration page. Is there some php file or settings page where I can modify this behavior? I don't want such information to be required at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must have atleast one of them fields i.e. either username or email, because you cannot login with just a password.

In the following example, I have used just username to register and ignored email field and registered a user via ajax call, this code is from functions.php file.

```
function register() {
    global $wpdb;
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $userdata = array('user_login' => $username, 'user_pass' => $password);
    if (isset($username) && $username != '') {
        $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);
        wp_set_current_user($user_id, $username);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, true, false);
        $_SESSION['registered'] = 1;
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', time());
        if (is_wp_error($user_id)) {
            $error_string = $user_id->get_error_message();
            echo $error_string;
        }
        echo $user_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would like to use the phone number instead of username/email. Also, at which file.php do I add this code to?

Comment: You can use phone number in username field. Please read more about functions.php on where to add the code

Comment: Great. Thank you.